# Spring Boot can't autowire @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-restcontroller

Here is my `FileStorageProperties` class:

```
 @Data
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
 public class FileStorageProperties {
       private String uploadDir;
 }
```

This gives me saying : *not registered via @enableconfigurationproperties or marked as spring component*.

And here is my `FileStorageService` :

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {

private final Path fileStorageLocation;

@Autowired
public FileStorageService(FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
    this.fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir())
            .toAbsolutePath().normalize();

    try {
        Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new FileStorageException("Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
    }
}

public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
    // Normalize file name
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
        if(fileName.contains("..")) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileName);
        }

        // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
        Path targetLocation = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        return fileName;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new FileStorageException("Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again!", ex);
    }
}

public Resource loadFileAsResource(String fileName) {
    try {
        Path filePath = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName).normalize();
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
        if(resource.exists()) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new MyFileNotFoundException("File not found " + fileName);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new MyFileNotFoundException("File not found " + fileName, ex);
    }
}
}
```

This gives me error saying : *could not autowire no beans of type found*.

And here is my project structure :

[image: Spring Boot can't autowire @ConfigurationProperties - project structure]

And when I try to run it, it gives me :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mua.cse616.Service.FileStorageService required a bean of type 'com.mua.cse616.Property.FileStorageProperties' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mua.cse616.Property.FileStorageProperties' in your configuration.

---

**How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Please add `@Component` annotation in `FileStorageProperties`.

Comment: or you can add  `@EnableConfigurationProperties({ FileStorageProperties.class})` to any of  `@Configuration` annotated class.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is expected as `@ConfigurationProperties` does not make a class a Spring `Component`. Mark the class with `@Component` and it should work. Note that a class can only be injected if it is a `Component`.

**Edit: From Spring 2.2+** ([Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#configurationproperties-scanning))
`@ConfigurationProperties` scanning
Classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` can now be found via classpath scanning as an alternative to using `@EnableConfigurationProperties` or `@Component`.

**Add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` to your application to enable scanning.**

Comment: But Baeldung saying that ["As, of Spring Boot 2.2, Spring finds and registers @ConfigurationProperties classes via classpath scanning."](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#1-spring-boot-22)

Comment: The documentation does point out that you need to provide `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`. I am updating the answer accordingly

Comment: @Prashant It also points out "In addition, we can use the ConfigurationPropertiesScan annotation to scan custom locations for configuration property classes:".    So does that mean if i don't need to scan custom locations, i can omit this scan annotation??

Answer (score 4):

**Try to annotate with `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Component`**

In here , Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` is annotation for externalized configuration.if you are trying  to inject property value from a property file to a class, you  can add `@ConfigurationProperties` at a class level with stereotype annotations such as `@Component` or add `@ConfigurationProperties` to a `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 4):

In my case
I had
`@ConfigurationProperties("limits-service")` in my class but missed
`@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` in the main application class `LimitsServiceApplication`

adding `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` to `LimitsServiceApplication` worked.

Answer (score 2):

add bellow annotation in FileStorageProperties class:

```
@Component
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `@EnableConfigurationProperties(FileStorageProperties.class);` on your main class